# How to do Inner join on multiple columns in Nhibernate Query Over

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I want to do a query over for one of my entity but I want to get done for multiple columns.

Questions (Table)

```
Id  Name    OpenId     CloseId
1   A         1          NULL
2   B         2           3
3   C         4           5
4   D         6           7
5   E         8           9
```

Now the GroupTable is

```
Id  Name
1   AA
2   BB
3   CC
4   DD
5   EE
6   FF
7   GG
8   HH
9   II
```

Now I want to do a queryOver on Question table with both OpenId and CloseId which are from the group table. How can I do.

I can achieve easily from the SQL query like.

```
select * from questions q 
inner join GroupTable g on q.OpenId = g.Id Or q.CloseId = g.Id
```

How can I get this through Queryover ?

The class structure looks like this :

```
public class Question
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public GroupTable OpenTable { get; set; }
        public GroupTable CloseTable { get; set; }
    }

    public class GroupTable
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I have updated the question with Class entities

Comment: The ON part of the JOIN will **never* be populated with `OR` ... if NHibernate is used. It will be joined either for Open or Close property. Or both - but then TWO joins will be created... so the select intended above won't work

Comment: so what would be the best way to do this ? through sql Query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try it.

```
            GroupTable openTable = null;
            GroupTable closeTable = null;
            Question ques = null;
            List<Question> quesList = new List<Question>();

            quesList = session.QueryOver<Question>(() => ques)
                .JoinAlias(() => ques.CloseTable, () => closeTable)
                .JoinAlias(() => ques.OpenTable, () => openTable)
                .Where(() => ques.CloseTable == closeTable && ques.OpenTable == openTable)
                .List().ToList();
```

Comment: that has syntax error on  "session.QueryOver<Question>(() => ques) "

Comment: can you share Question class and mapping files with me

Comment: I don't think this will work. It is doing an inner join on both columns so this would be the correct answer for q.OpenId = g.Id AND q.CloseId = g.Id. His question was about OR.